# Several conditions in the loop - magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to show the H1 tag - if the values ​​are present. But if the values ​​are not present - do not display H1. H1 should be shown only once. I know that this code runs in a loop.

```
    <?php $attributes = Mage::helper('amshopby/attributes')->getFilterableAttributes(); ?>
    <?php $filterBlockName = 'amshopby/catalog_layer_filter_attribute'; ?>
    <?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute): ?>
    <?php if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'my_attribute'): ?>
    <?php $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init(); ?>

    <h1>Artist list</h1>

    <?php foreach($result->getItems() as $option): ?>
    <?php if (($option->getValue() == '24') || ($option->getValue() == '31')): ?>
        <?php echo '<li><a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a</li>'; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>   
    <?php endforeach; ?> 

    <?php endif; ?>         
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

It should look:

**Artist list**

- Barry White
- Alice cooper

But if values are not present - does not display anything.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach($result->getItems() as $option): ?>
<?php if (($option->getValue() == '24') || ($option->getValue() == '31')): ?>
    <?php if (!$artist_list): ?>
        <?php echo '<h1>Artist list</h1>'; ?>
        <?php $artist_list = true; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo '<li><a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a</li>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thnx! It works!